# How to perform Localization using sqlite stored data-iOS App?

Tags: ios, sqlite, localization

In my app i am doing localization to support mutiple languages. For that i am creating .string file and using the following method:

`-(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*)key;`

I am using the Key_value concept for this. its working fine. But My question is:

Let say i have a sqlite database which has all the different languages string which needs to be localized.

For eg: **for spanish**

```
"Username" = "nombre de usuario";
"Password" = "contraseña";
"Submit" = "presentar";
```

**for french**

```
"Username" = "nom d'utilisateur";
"Password" = "mot de passe";
"Submit" = "soumettre";
```

all this is insert in a **sqlite database**.

How can we perform localization with the app that way?

Comment: If you have a database that has the terms in it you either must store the localized terms there (use a column to select language) or run the strings through NSLocalizedString after fetching them (though in this latter case getting the strings into the translation table might require some thought).

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have all strings traduction within one db, you need to have an intermediate data structure that will act as a bridge between the db and your method to localize the string.

You could make use of a `dictionary` for e.g to store the key string identifier and as a value an array that contain all the languages traduction. You will need to feed this data structure once then.

Note that the recommended way is to use `.strings` files for localisation so you need to provide us good raison why you can't take this approach.

Comment: 1.we want to update the localization db.-from webserver if possible
2.we are having list of string which is present in UITableView.--which need to localize as well

Answer (score -1):

If those are titles/texts for UIButtons and UILabels use the following syntax in your viewController:

> ```
> NSString *buttonString = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"viewController-title-button-username", @"Localizable", nil);
> self.username_label.text = buttonString;
> ```

And in your Localizable.strings file you do(you must add localization to your project and set this file to be localized to spanish):

> "viewController-title-button-username" = "nombre de usuario";
>
> "tabbar-item1" = "item1 in spanish";
>
> "tabbar-item2" = "item2 in spanish";
>
> "tabbar-item3" = "item3 in spanish";

And the same for the Localizable.strings you have set to be the french:

> "viewController-title-button-username" = "nom d'utilisateur";
>
> "tabbar-item1" = "item1 in french";
>
> "tabbar-item2" = "item2 in french";
>
> "tabbar-item3" = "item3 in french";

For your tabbar name, put this in your viewDidLoad for each viewController you have. Just change 1, 2, 3 etc.:

> ```
> NSString *name = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"tabbar-item1", @"Main", nil);
> self.title = name;
> ```

On the other hand if you are getting either an .xml or retrieving using REST you can do the following:

```
//Get the name of what you want eg. spanish-data or french-data
NSString *name = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"xml-locations-string", @"Main", nil);

//What to add at the end
NSString *append = @".xml";

//Merge strings to what you want to retrieve: spanish-data.xml
NSMutableString *file = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", name, append];

//From which URL
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.myDomain.com/ProjectName/";

//Create full URL http://www.myDomain.com/ProjectName/spanish-data.xml
NSString *fileUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", urlString, file];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileUrl];
```

The data you get back will now be the localized version. And you can use that to set table data or whatever you need.

This is the super simple and therefor not optimized way of doing it. Works for REST as well, you just need to reconstruct to fit your project.

Comment: doesnt match the question at all im afraid. his source is a sqlite table

Comment: I know but that didn't make much sense as it looks like he is trying to set the text of labels and buttons. And why use data from a sqlite table when that's exactly what localization does?

Comment: maybe because he is loading the strings from a server or has it for windows or so... I agree it isnt a good idea ;)

Comment: i have a menu list which need to localized which is shown in uitableview......and i have to also localized the uitabbarbutton tittle

Comment: Exactly my point. I am just trying to help him use localization as it was intended and taking advantage of the built in functionality. Instead of writing code for him.Just my way to try and help here on SO.

Comment: May I ask why you are collecting this data from a sqlite db and not using Localizable.strings to do this? How I usually do it is that elements like that UIButtons, UILabels, menu items, tabbar names etc. I get from the Localizable.strings file. Any content data that I need I retrieve from a sqlite, REST, xml, json. As that data is something that I want to be able to change and update so it updates in the app. As for tabbar titles don't really need to be updatable in the same way.

Comment: Plus, Xcode also lets you localize XIBs and Storyboards directly, without even using a strings file.

Comment: Just suppose that the OP has an application with hundreds of different screens, driven from a database.  The database defines what labels and buttons to display and, by way of function codes, what to do with the button presses, etc.  And suppose that this database is relatively dynamic, either downloaded on the fly or at least updated frequently.  Splitting the text into an entirely different structure would be a maintenance nightmare.